# Determine if a very large array contains duplicate

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, duplicates

For a normal size array, we can determine if it contains duplicate by sorting or using hashset, etc. 
But if we have a very large array, say the length is 10 billion, how could we determine if it contains duplicate?

Follow up: if we know there must exists one duplicate in the this large array, how could we determine which one is it?

My idea is using sorting, but I don't if there is a better way to handle these situations.

Comment: You can't do better than the `O(n log n)` from a comparison sort unless you know more about the data held in the array. You can only use the comparison sort if you have a way to determine if items are in order, otherwise you need to compare each item to each other item, which is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Please specify whether that is 10^13 (large compared to 2015 main memory) or 10^10 (big). What is the required level of confidence that the answer is correct? -> [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) (On the other hand, if we were talking 33-bit values …)

Comment: what kind of data are you comparing, e.g., strings, numbers? how large is each datum?

Answer (score 2):

First, bucket your data into K buckets with code like this.

```
files = array of K file handles
for each d in data {
    write d to files[hash(d) % K]
}
close each file
```

If you pick K large enough, each bucket will comfortably fit in RAM. Make sure to pick a good hash function, otherwise the buckets will be unbalanced. The actual code will also depend on the storage system you're using. For example, if you're using a regular hard disk, seeks are expensive and care needs to be taken to avoid thrashing the disk. One approach would be to read in as much data as will fit into RAM, and then iterate over it K times, appending to only one of the output files in each pass.

Next, simply go through each bucket in turn, and see if it contains any duplicates. You can use any efficient algorithm for detecting duplicates.

```
for each f in the K files {
    data = read f into RAM
    detect duplicates in data
}
```

An alternative solution would be to use a [map-reduce framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

The map step will look like this:

```
map(value) {
    emit(key=hash(value), value=value)
}
```

And the reduce step will look like this:

```
reduce(key, values) {
    if there's a duplicate in values {
        emit the duplicate value.
    }
}
```

Note, that each reducer will only see multiple values when there's a duplicate, or when there's hash collisions. If you've picked a reasonable hash function, the latter will be extremely rare.

Comment: How about adding a bloom filter to the detect duplicate part? Should make a good shortcut to say there isn't one.

Comment: This assumes reasonably fast random access (which would be typical of _arrays_ and is more likely with SSDs than with HDDs, tapes, punch-cards, stone tablets …)

Comment: @greybeard you're right.. I'll modify my answer to note that the actual code would have to be more careful.

Comment: @Reactormonk I don't know where you think a bloom filter would help. Given a large amount of data, a bloom filter will detect a false-positive duplicate with almost probability one.